# Color coding emacs being accessed remotely with putty

Tags: c++, unix, emacs, colors, putty

I use PuTTY to log on to my university's unix server and then start emacs and code in that. is there anyway to color code the code. Its C++ and ive been doing research for 2 hours and found nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to do a M-x font-lock-mode and see if that works.

You also might be running into a problem with the terminal emulation colors, as emacs does font-locking (coloring) of code pretty much automatically now.  Try running emacs with --color=always and see if that gives you color.

Comment: emacs --color=always (with a space between emacs and --color=always)

Comment: Good.  That problem stumped me for a while too.